# Swift 3 pass the cell data A view to B view, with fun didSelectRowAt indexPath crash after select row

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview, cell-array, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to pass the data A view to B view, it can build and show data in A view, but after I selected the cell, it crashed. And it shows the problem on the code.

`vcTwo.selectedzones.zones = [selectedCity]`

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

my code

**The struct mode:**

```
struct Location {
    var city: String!
    var zones = [String]()
}
var city = ["KHT", "TPAP", "TNNY"]

let kh = Location.init(city: "KHT", zones: ["sami", "zami", "zomi", "komi", "shini"])
let tpa = Location.init(city: "TPAP", zones: ["mid", "east", "anci", "zochi"])
let tnn = Location.init(city: "TNNY", zones: ["TN1","TN2", "TN3", "TN4", "TN5"])
```

**Here is the A viewController code:**

```
    import UIKit

class FirstViewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  }

   // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return city.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCell

          cell.firstLabel.text = city[indexPath.row]

          return cell
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let selectedCity = city[indexPath.row]
        let vcTwo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! secondViewController
         vcTwo.selectedzones.zones = [selectedCity]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcTwo, animated: true)

    }
 }
```

**The B viewController:**

```
import UIKit

class secondViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedzones: Location!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return selectedzones.zones.count
    }
```

Is there any part wrong in the func didSelectRowAt indexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the problem

```
     vcTwo.selectedzones.zones = [selectedCity]
```

you need to init the selectedZone in first Controller

```
     let kh = Location.init(city: "KHT", zones: ["sami", "zami", "zomi", "komi", "shini"])

     vcTwo.selectedzones = kh
```

Comment: Thank you !! It won't crash now~ but still can't pass the data to Bview,after i selected the row. It doest do anything. no crash no switch to next View

Comment: init the location in first controller with complete data as well. it will pass it

Comment: sorry, I am so new with programming!!! do you mean "var location = [Location]()"  above the func viewDidLoad() in first View ? or all my Location  of Struct

Comment: I update it, just run this code as it's static data, it will help you will understand the problem

Comment: Thank you so much ! lol every time i click the row always expect to see the next View show up, it still not happen now but i will keep working on it~ thanks  you guys help~this is where the fun from !! GO~

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class secondViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedzones = Location()
}
```

you are try to accesss `zones` but you have not allocate `Location` so it will crash.
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Optional ! use Optional ?

```
class secondViewController: UITableViewController {
var selectedzones: Location?

NOT 

class secondViewController: UITableViewController {
var selectedzones: Location!
```

Comment: thanks for the advice !!  both of them can show view A but B, but it is ok i will keep work on it !! your suggestion make me learn more , cool and appreciate it.